# GA Enhanced Ecommerce, transactions not tracking properly

Tags: google-analytics

This is referring to an ecommerce OpenCart site just for reference.

I recently installed a new payment gateway for a client - Barclay's EPDQ - which takes the customer off of the site onto the Barclays payment page. I'm using the Google Measurement Protocol to track the transaction, so I'm sending the Google session ID to the payment page and getting it back in a custom parameter so I can track the transaction.

The problem I'm having is that whilst the transaction is being recorded in Google analytics fine, it's just not registering it on the Checkout Behavior section, so it looks like there's 100% drop-off for the confirm order page. But the transactions are appearing under Overview and sales performance etc.

I'm logging the Google session ID before it's sent to the payment pages, and seeing that it's sending the exact ID back so I don't know why it's not associating it with the session that was sent to the payment page.

I've set up tracking in the same way for another site (which uses PayPal), and it works fine, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Here's a basic overview of the process:

- Confirm page: Get the session ID and put it into the custom field of the confirm order form.
- -> Send order data including session ID to external payment page (confirmed it does match up)
- <- Payment page calls a callback function on the site with the session ID in the post data. Google measurement protocol uses this ID to send the transaction data to Google.
- User redirected to success page.

Can anyone think of anything I might be missing? Or some other way to test and track what's going on?